# how to dismiss top_snackbar_flutter manually by a button on it?

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I needed a calling popup screen like WhatsApp and other apps like that, so I used top_snackbar_flutter. I have two buttons on it to accept/reject and my only problem is that when I press buttons I want to top_snackbar_flutter be dismissed but it does not.

Comment: do you mean you want to close the popup snack bar with a button?

Comment: actually its not a simple snackbar.its partially a complex popup sheet

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pacakage "another_flushbar" you can dismiss the bar by sliding it

https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar

and a yt tutorial.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-XEIkUfN4M